# Django cannot find custom template tags

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I've created a templatetags folder within my app, with an __init__.py + active.py inside it, and Django can't find it, even if the app is in INSTALLED_APPS:

```
''active'' is not a valid tag library: Template library 'active' not found, tried
django.templatetags.'active',website.home.templatetags.'active',
django_extensions.templatetags.'active',django.contrib.flatpages.templatetags.'active',
django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.'active',
django.contrib.admin.templatetags.'active'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably tried to [load you template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#load) like this:

```
{% load 'active_tags' %}
```

Try this instead:

```
{% load active_tags %}
```